# Zemirot different customs in Shabbat Hol Hamoed

Tags: minhag, shabbat-songs, shalosh-regalim

Is there any source that mentions the differences of customs in Shabat Hol Hamoed Zemirot? I would like to know: what are the different customs? Which Kehila holds each custom? What is the reason for the difference between customs? or alternatively what is the reason for each custom?